# Move an object in a direction using a directional vector

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

Okay so I have a game that has object floating in the air. I want to simulate the wind by pushing the floating objects in the same direction of the wind.

I have been looking on the internet but I have found no information on how to move an object by a (directional) vector instead of moving it towards a point in space.

Vector.lerp, translate etc. all uses a point of reference where as, I would like to use a directional vector of length (ideally 1) from the center of the object towards it s wanted direction. This is possible with in-built forward vector but I wanted to do it even if the object is rotating on itself.

Anyone has an idea or a direction to go into?

PS: The directional vectors of all objects should be parallel. The only idea I have so far is to set a point by the wind vector and adjust it based for each objects. But that seems a bit complicated and bothersome to do for such a stupid task.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is simply a matter of adding a vector to the object's position (or velocity if you want more realism)

```
transform.position += wind * Time.deltaTime
```

or

```
rigidbody.velocity += wind * Time.deltaTime
```

The second option requires the GameObject to have a Rigidbody component

Comment: ah yes how stupid am i to forget this. I was over thinking this. thx

Comment: Accept his answer if that solved your problem. Thats the right way of saying thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think Transform has a member called Translate which handles the translation as a direction:

```
myobject.transform.Translate(2,0,0);
```

This moves the object 2 units to the right of where it is now.

EDIT: here it is http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Translate.html